# Fractional scrollHeight?

Tags: javascript, scroll

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.scrollHeight:

> This property will round the value to an integer. If you need a fractional value, use [`element.getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect).

Except... `element.getBoundingClientRect()` does not return the scrollHeight. How would one get a fractional scrollHeight? Is it possible?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I think I might have the solution:

```
var rect = element.getBoundingClientRect()
var scrollHeight = element.scrollHeight + (parseInt(rect.height) - rect.height)
var scrollWidth  = element.scrollWidth  + (parseInt(rect.width)  - rect.width)
```

Comment: This does not work in general. Example: `<div id="element" style="height: 10px; overflow: auto;"><div style="height: 42.42px"></div></div>`

Comment: Well, one solution might be to set the containing element to use min-height instead of height (even temporarily, if you want).

Comment: this can't possibly work as there is no way of knowing whether the scrollHeight/scrollWidth have been rounded up to their integer value, or rounded down

Answer (score 0):

Inside the scrollable `outerEl`, have an `innerEl` element contain all content, so the scrollHeight equals the element height. Then you can get scroll height in decimals using `innerEl.getBoundingClientRect().height`.

Note that you need to make sure there is no margin between `outerEl` and `innerEl`. Set padding of `outerEl` to 0, margin of `innerEl`, first child of `innerEl`, and last child of `innerEl` to 0.

```js
document.getElementById("scrollHeight").innerText = document.getElementById("outer").scrollHeight
document.getElementById("boundingRect").innerText = document.getElementById("inner").getBoundingClientRect().height
```

```css
#outer {
  height: 50px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 0px;
}

#inner {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.content {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">
    <div class="content">
      outerEl.scrollHeight: <span id="scrollHeight">?</span>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      innerEl.getBoundingClientRect().height: <span id="boundingRect">?</span>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      You must make sure there is no margin between outer element and inner element.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```